# Line graph on IOS

Tags: ios, html, cocoa, swift, graphing

I am looking to do a basic line graph on IOS. However, I also need the ability for the user to zoom in on the graph (which is a timeline) for additional detail. What library is recommended to pursue to do this? What about doing this function in a WebView and HTML, rather than as a native capability?

Answer (score 0):

[Core Plot](https://github.com/core-plot) is a good choice. You'll need to use the code from the `release-2.0` branch or wait for the 2.0 release (hopefully soon) if you intend to use it in a Swift app.

Comment: Is there a Quickstart? The iOS documentation on GitHub contains circular links.

Comment: @mac389 Best place to start is to look through the example apps included with Core Plot, especially the *Plot Gallery*. If you get stuck, ask a question here on StackOverflow.